# analog and digital clocks not showing correct time

Tags: android

I have written simple xml file to show the analog, digital clocks. Now the time is 2:32 but the clocks are showing the time as 09:32. Can you please help me. thank you

```
<AnalogClock android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<DigitalClock android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now system time is 2:48 time displaying is 09:48

Comment: Please show the code which is causing the problem.

Comment: what is your system clock time?

Comment: are you using emulator? or testing on device?

Comment: Sorry guys. I got it. I had set the time in the emulator and changed GMT settings. It is done

Comment: @user609282: If you solved the problem, please add your solution as an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Emulator go to settings -> date and time -> Uncheck the automatic (Use network provided values) and then set the time. Now it will display the correct time